# 先に used with nouns

Tags: particles, particle-に

I quite often come across sentences that post-fixes 先に to a place. For example: xxx駅先に各駅に止まります or 待ち合わせ先に直帰

I know that 先 can either mean before or after, and after reading Takumi Sueda's answer to this post [I am struggling with the sometimes conflicting uses of 先](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/i-am-struggling-with-the-sometimes-conflicting-uses-of-%E5%85%88) , it seems that only when there's a これから before the 先, would 先 imply "after". Going back to the question at hand, applying this logic would mean that the 先 here implies before rather then after, which wouldn't make sense. Assuming that the 先 here implies after, a very literal translation would be "From xxx station onwards, (train) will stop in a 各駅 manner (stops at every station)". I am assuming that the xxx駅先 is a noun, and the question that arises here is, since xxx駅先 is a noun, would using other particles that can be used as noun (for example: が、を、等) be ok? Example: xxx駅先がきれいです to mean (the places) after xxx station is beautiful?

Comment: X駅先に各駅に止まります makes no sense. Perhaps you've misheard X駅**より**先は各駅に止まります or X駅**から**先は各駅に止まります.

Comment: The 先 in 待ち合わせ先 is different from the other one. In this case 先 marks a destination, like バイト先 and 旅先.

Comment: のmay also be a good indicator, i.e. in the case of xxxの先... it would be after xxx...